# How can I use modify NERDCommenter's behavior to comment *ALL* lines that are selected

Tags: vim

In Vim, when I comment a multi-line visual selection using NERDCommenter, the blank lines in the selection are not commented.  In the example below, I select all 5 lines and type "\cl" (for NERDCommenterAlignLeft), but the 3rd line, which is blank, is not commented.

Before:

```
" Normalize Markdown : Remove Trailing # From Headers
nnoremap <Leader>qq :%s/ \+#\+ *$//gc<CR>

" Normalize Markdown : Remove Trailing Whitespace
nnoremap <Leader>qw :%s/\s\+$//gc<CR>
```

After:

```
" " Normalize Markdown : Remove Trailing # From Headers
" nnoremap <Leader>qq :%s/ \+#\+ *$//gc<CR>

" " Normalize Markdown : Remove Trailing Whitespace
" nnoremap <Leader>qw :%s/\s\+$//gc<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it has been implemented in NERDCommenter plugin. If you open the plugin file (NERD_commenter.vim) and look for a function named `s:CanCommentLine`, you will see that it has the following check:

```
" make sure we don't comment lines that are just spaces or tabs or empty.
if theLine =~ "^[ \t]*$"
    return 0
endif
```

So, before the plugin goes ahead to comment a line, it checks if it is an empty line. If so, the plugin does not comment it and skips to the next line.

A quickfix would be to simply remove this part of the code from your plugin file.

Comment: It seemed right, but didn't work for me. I'll let you know if I discover why. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: Solved. I was toggling comments instead of commenting directly. In that case, the function to modify is `s:CanToggleCommentLine`.